# non-static method isSpam(MailItem) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, bluej

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java non-static method getBalance cannot be referenced from a static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973746/java-non-static-method-getbalance-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

I am trying to access isSpam method of another class but it is not allowing me. It keeps saying that non-static method cannot be referenced. Can I get a bit of help please?
Here is my code for isSpam and the one to check

`public void post(MailItem item)`

```
    if (SpamChecker.isSpam(item)) {
    }
    String name = item.getTo();
    if(!items.containsKey(name)) {
        items.put(name,new ArrayList<MailItem>());
    }
    items.get(name).add(item);
}
```

and here's the isSpam from SpamChecker class

`public boolean isSpam(MailItem item)
    {
        if (item.getSubject().toLowerCase().startsWith("spam")){`

```
        return true;
    } else if(item.getSubject().toLowerCase().contains("online pharmacy")){
        return true;
    } else if(item.getSubject().toLowerCase().contains("cheap viagra")) {
        return true;
    } else if(item.getSubject().toLowerCase().contains("generic viagra")) {
        return true;
    } else if(item.getSubject().toLowerCase().contains("fake watches")) {
        return true;
    } else if(item.getSubject().toLowerCase().contains("replica watches")) {
        return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write as :

```
SpamChecker spamChecker = new SpamChecker();
if (spamChecker.isSpam(item)) {
   // <--- your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers of Dantuch or Yogendra are good, or you can, as well, make the method isPam() static.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding `isSpam()` method is a **Non-static** one, so to access this create an **instance of class** `SpamChecker`.

**Eg:**

```
SpamChecker spamCheck = new SpamChecker();

if (spamCheck.isSpam(item)){



}
```